# Ubuntu crash in a Dell inspiron 7373 when screen is turned off

Tags: 18.04, dell, 19.10, 20.04

My system is crashing when my laptop (Dell inspiron 7373) screen is turned off (tested in 18.04, 19.10 and 20.04). It happens when I suspend the laptop or when I lock the screen (super+l). I can reproduce the issue using `xset dpms force off`. Some times it just works, but most of the time it just crash and I need to turn off the laptop using the physical button, even "SysRq REISUB" does not work for rebooting when system crash.

Any idea? I will be grateful for any help.

UPDATE: I have opened this bug report on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1878007

Comment: You OS tags are too many.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen is because I have tested the issue in all those versions

Comment: Then please include that in your question so we know why you have the many tags

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen done